# C++ Simple image collision

Tags: c++, image, collision

I have done a bunch of searches but i was unsure what answers apply to my problem. Im making a simple game where on a timer a image moves down while you move your "character" left and right. How would i go about making it subtract 1 from a variable when they collide? I can post code if needed

Comment: is your problem detecting a collision or substracting one from something? yes, some (short) code extract would help.

Comment: its detecting the collision and heres the code http://pastebin.com/mirW1bQM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about collision detection? I would probably need code, but I am assuming you know the width and height, x and y position of your objects, and that they are rectangular. Checking if they intersect should be trivial. Check if object 1's (y + height) is greater than object 2's (y + height) and that object 1's (x + width) is greater that object 2's x. Do similar things for other edges.

EDIT: In fact, you could run collision detection on another thread just do it doesn't bog down your UI thread.

Comment: One of my issues is finding the X and Y i know the width and height.

Comment: Do you not store the object's position? How are you handling entities if not?

Comment: Okay, what library are you using? Could you post some code? That would be helpful.

Comment: No i do not store the position sorry if im new but what are entities? and heres my code http://pastebin.com/mirW1bQM

Comment: Entities are objects. What graphics library are you using?

Comment: Just the stock one used by Visual Studio 2008 i just used picture boxes.

Comment: So you are using a Windows Forms Application and you are manipulating the position of the picture boxes? A PictureBox control has a Location property. So you can say (i think) PictureBox.Location.X to grab its x value, and same for y.

Comment: yep a windows for application, is there a if statement to compare the x and y of two objects?

Comment: I was thinking about putting a if statement something like this" If picturebox1.location = picturebox2.location lives--"

Comment: Well, that would only be true if their corners were matched up, pixel for pixel. Try this:
`if(picturebox1.Location.Y + picturebox1.Size.Height > picturebox2.Location.Y + picturebox2.Size.Height && picturebox1.Location.X + picturebox1.Size.Width > picturebox2.Location.X){ lives-- }`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shape of the characters. For a simple case of both being circles, you could just find the distance between the centers at every step, and triggering the collision when it reaches less than the sum of radii. For the case of rectangular shapes, it would also be pretty simple.

Comment: Its a rectangle is there a simple way to find the x y every time it moves and check if the x y is the same as the "falling blocks"?